# Apply kivy touch behaviours at the root: Be able to sense the double, triple tap, and long touch anywhere on the main screen

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivymd

Here, I have a root (in kivy file) which is the only screen of my app. Now,  would like to detect double, triple, and long touch on the screen. But, I want that to be detectable anywhere on the screen, not only by clicking on some items listed in my screen. This will be updated later to work with pyttsx3, meaning: if a triple_tap is recorded, the task being read (task_being_read) as part of allTasks will be deleted from the dictionary allTasks. If a long_touch is captured, the lecture of the tasks stop and the lecture of the subtasks of the task_being_read are read. Finally, a double tap, if detected, will stop the lecture of teh task_being_read and move on to the lecture of the next tasks directly.

Here is the main code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
import pyttsx3
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior


class TaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, task_text="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_text.text = task_text

class SubTaskShowContent(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


allTasks = {}
currentSelectedTask = ""
class MyApp(MDApp, TouchBehavior):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    database_file = 'database2.txt'
    task_list_dialog = None
    subtask_list_dialog = None
    dialog = None

def build(self):
    return Builder.load_file('main2.kv')


def load_tasks_from_file(self):
        file = open("database2.txt", "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        task = None
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line[0] == "*":
                task = line[1:]
                allTasks[task] = []
            else:
                subtask = line[1:]
                allTasks[task].append(subtask)
        print(allTasks)

    def on_start(self):
        self.load_tasks_from_file()
        self.view_tasks(allTasks)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.second_function, 2)

    def second_function(self, dt):
        self.read_me()



def task_dialog(self):
    if self.task_list_dialog:
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

    self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
        title="Create a Task",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=TaskDialogContent()
    )
    self.task_list_dialog.open()



def subtask_dialog(self, key):
    if self.subtask_list_dialog:
        self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

    global currentSelectedTask
    print("current task = ", currentSelectedTask)
    self.subtask_list_dialog = MDDialog(
        title=f"Add a subtask to {key} ",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=SubTaskDialogContent()
    )
    currentSelectedTask = key #-----------This is the one to work with for the touches. I need a new varibale that
    print(currentSelectedTask)
    self.subtask_list_dialog.open()



def add_task(self, taskname):
    allTasks[taskname] = []
    self.view_tasks(allTasks) #just for debugging


def add_subtask(self, subtaskname):
    # subtask_text = self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text
    allTasks[currentSelectedTask].append(subtaskname)
    print("After adding the subtask")
    print(allTasks)

def view_tasks(self, allTasks):
    print(allTasks) #just to view the tasks after adding them
    self.root.ids.container.clear_widgets()
    for key in allTasks:
        item = OneLineListItem(
            MDIconButton(
                icon="tray-plus",
                pos_hint={"center_x": .92, "center_y": 0.5},
                on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.subtask_dialog(key)
            ),
            MDIconButton(
                icon="trash-can-outline",
                pos_hint={"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
                on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.delete_task(key)
            ),
            text= key,
            on_release = lambda instance, key = key: app.view_subtasks(key)
            )
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)

def view_subtasks(self, key):
    global currentSelectedTask
    currentSelectedTask = key # Here I am changing the value of currentSelectedTask to be teh last task that was selected.
    print("------>The current selected task is " + currentSelectedTask)
    currenttasks = allTasks[key]
    print(currenttasks)
    self.show_subtasks_dialog(currenttasks)

def show_subtasks_dialog(self, subtasks):
    if self.dialog:
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    content = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical", adaptive_height=True)

    for subtask in subtasks:
        content.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=subtask))

    self.dialog = MDDialog(
        title=f"Subtasks for {currentSelectedTask}",
        type="custom",
        content_cls=content,
    )

    self.dialog.open()

def delete_task(self,key):

    widget_to_remove = None
    for widget in self.root.ids.container.children:
        if isinstance(widget, OneLineListItem) and widget.text == key:
            widget_to_remove = widget
            break
    if widget_to_remove:
        self.root.ids.container.remove_widget(widget_to_remove)

    allTasks.pop(key, None)
    print(allTasks)


def close_task_dialog(self, *args):
    self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

def close_subtask_dialog(self):
    self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

def on_stop(self):
    self.write_to_file()

def write_to_file(self):
    with open("database2.txt", "w") as file:
        for task, subtasks in allTasks.items():
            file.write(f"*{task}\n")
            for subtask in subtasks:
                file.write(f"+{subtask}\n")

def read_me(self):
    self.rate = self.engine.getProperty('rate')
    self.engine.setProperty('rate', 80)
    for key in allTasks:
        task_being_read = key
        print("The task being read is ", task_being_read)
        self.engine.say("Task" + str(key))
        self.engine.runAndWait()


    def on_long_touch(self, *args):
        print("<on_long_touch> event")

    def on_double_tap(self, *args):
        print("<on_double_tap> event")

    def on_triple_tap(self, *args):
        print("<on_triple_tap> event")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is the kivy code

```
MDFloatLayout:
MDLabel:
    id: task_label
    halign: "center"
    markup: True
    text:"[b][u][size=48]Your Task Manager[/size][/u][/b]"
    pos_hint: {"y": 0.45}

ScrollView:
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
    size_hint: 0.9, 0.8
    MDList:
        id: container

MDFloatingActionButton:
    icon: "plus-thick"
    on_release: app.task_dialog()
    elevation_normal: 12
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "y": 0.04}


<TaskDialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Add a task ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())


BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "SAVE"
        on_release: (app.add_task(task_text.text), app.close_task_dialog())
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "CANCEL"
        on_release: app.close_task_dialog()


<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: subtask_content 
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

GridLayout:
    rows: 1

    MDTextField:
        id: subtask_text
        hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
        max_text_length: 50
        on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "SAVE"
        on_release: app.add_subtask(subtask_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "CANCEL"
        on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()


<SubTaskShowContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: subtasks_grid
            cols: 1
            spacing: dp(5)
```